# Is this "injecting function (parser) to the anonymous implementation of Action trait"?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I don't quite understand this syntax (the one with the red square). Is this a case of "injecting function (parser) to the anonymous implementation of Action trait".

I've tried googling to confirm / discard that, but haven't found any article with the answer.

Or... is there a companion object (in Play 2) whose name is "Action", whose apply method takes an (optional) BodyParser parameter?

Thanks in advance for clearing this up for me!

Best regards,
Raka

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or... is there a companion object (in Play 2) whose name is "Action", whose apply method takes an (optional) BodyParser parameter?

[Yes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action$) (except for the "optional" part; there are also overloads which don't take `BodyParser` but their `block` argument types are different as well).

Comment: Thanks Alexey & Mohit.

Got it. This parallel structure was a bit funny to chew at first, I'm quite new to Scala.

But I got it now. So basically I have to create a class that extends the Action trait (implement my functionality there), and a (companion) object that extends ActionBuilder (instantiate my actual action there).

Answer (score 4):

With regards to standards, "Action" with capital A can only be companion object.

From
   https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala

```
object Action extends ActionBuilder[Request] {...}

trait ActionBuilder[+R[_]] extends ActionFunction[Request, R] {
final def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: R[A] => Result): Action[A] = async(bodyParser)       { req: R[A] =>
Future.successful(block(req))
```

ActionBuilder's apply method takes bodyParser as a parameter.